# How can I add an object with all variables and not just one variable to a shared preferences method in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to generate a search history but using shared preference methods like getstringList and setStringList.

With the search variable I get the selected search and I store it in a list called historiaMenuPrincipal.
I have to store that list in the SetStringList method of shared preferences but when I try to cast it or add that method,
I can only store one variable and what I want is to store all the variables and then display it on the console or in some text widget.
Here is the code::

```
 Class BBC{
    List<SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal=[];
        IconButton(
                     icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                     onPressed: () async {
                       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                     
                       final busqueda = await showSearch(
                           context: context,
                           delegate: SearchDelegateMenuPrincipal(
                               "Buscar...", this.historialMenuPrincipal)
                       );
                       if (busqueda != null ) {
                         historialMenuPrincipal.removeWhere((item) =>
                         item.apodo == busqueda.apodo);
                         this.historialMenuPrincipal.insert(0, busqueda);
                        Final names = historialMenuPrincipal.map((e) => e.apodo).toList();
                        prefs.setStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences",names);
                           var  getpre =   prefs.getStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences");
                           print(getpre.asMap()[0]);
                       }
                     }
                 )
    
    }
    
    class SearchDelegateMenuPrincipal  extends SearchDelegate<SearchDelegateModel>{
    List<SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal=[];
    var PerfilSeleccionado; 
List <String> historialbusquedapreferences=[];
    Future<void> InitRetornarHistorialB() async {
    
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        historialbusquedapreferences = prefs.getStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences");
    // or do something her with de shared preferences
      }
       
    @override
      Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
      return historialbusquedapreferences .length <= 0 ? MensajeHistorialBusquedaVacio():
      HistorialBusqueda2(context ); 
      }
    
    }
     @override
      Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child:  IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed:() => this.close(context, PerfilSeleccionado)
        ),
      );
      }
    
    Widget HistorialBusqueda2(BuildContext context,List <SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal)  {
    InitRetornarHistorialBusqueda();
    return child:StatefulBuilder(
     children: [
     historialbusquedapreferences.length <= 0 ? MensajeHistorialBusquedaVacio() :GestureDetector(),
    Container(
     child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: historialbusquedapreferences.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context,i)
    {
     return ListTile(
     leading: namebusqueda(i),);))]);}
    
    Widgetnamebusqueda(int i){
    return Text(historialbusquedapreferences[i] == null ? "no data" :historialbusquedapreferences[i].apodo);
    }
    
    ////////////////////////
    List MenuPrincipalViewproductFromJson(String str) => List<SearchDelegateModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => SearchDelegateModel.fromJson(x)));
    class SearchDelegateModel{
     String apodo;
      String name;
    SearchDelegateModel({this.apodo,this.name})
    factory SearchDelegateModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
        return SearchDelegateModel(
            name: parsedJson['Name'],
            apodo : parsedJson['Apodo'])}
    }
```

Comment: convert the object to json and then store it in the sharedpreferences

Comment: how can i convert the object(busqueda <SearchDelegateModel>) to json??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have several solutions:

**First solution (if you need to use `setStringList` function):**

`setStringList` function accept List of String, in your case you try to pass `List<SearchDelegateModel>` to it, this is wrong.

To solve problem, map your list `historialMenuPrincipal` to list of String, then use function like this:

```
await prefs.setStringList('items', <String>['Earth', 'Moon', 'Sun']);
```

**Second solution (if you need to save list as JSON String):**

1- Add `toJson()` function to `SearchDelegateModel` class, this is full code of class:

```
class SearchDelegateModel{
  String apodo;
  String name;
  
  SearchDelegateModel({this.apodo, this.name});
  
  factory SearchDelegateModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return SearchDelegateModel(
      name: parsedJson['Name'],
      apodo: parsedJson['Apodo'],
    );
  }
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'Apodo': apodo,
    'Name': name,
  };
}
```

2- To save array to `SharedPreferences`, iterate `historialMenuPrincipal` list to be list of `JSON` like this:

```
List<SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal = [];

// here you can add,delete,update data of historialMenuPrincipal list

// convert the list to JSON
List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonList = [];
for (SearchDelegateModel item in historialMenuPrincipal) {
  jsonList.add(item.toJson());
}
String jsonString = jsonEncode(jsonList);

// now we can save jsonString to SharedPreferences like this
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('HistorialBusquedaPreferences', jsonString);
```

3- To read value from `SharedPreferences` as `List<SearchDelegateModel>` like this:

```
List<SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal = [];

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String historialString = prefs.getString('HistorialBusquedaPreferences');

if (historialString != null) {
  List<dynamic> decodedList = json.decode(historialString);
  historialMenuPrincipal = decodedList.map((item) => SearchDelegateModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
}
```

Comment: i did  historialMenuPrincipal.map((e) => e.apodo).toList();  but the problem is that it only stores one variable in the setstringlist method of the shared preferences and I want the whole object to show all the necessary variables

Comment: @Anes plese update your question with code of `SearchDelegateModel` so i can help you

Comment: I updated the question and the line of code that I wrote in the comment was already

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It is not working correctly. The for loop adds a null value to me. Like this::  [{0: LiioM, 1: 30}, {0: Usuario B., 1: 39}, {0: null, 1: null}, {0: Usuario B., 1: 39}]

Comment: When I want to print it returns null. i print like this::   print(historialMenuPrincipal[0].apodo);(this line is after decode part)

Comment: You do not need to print variables to check their values, as you can use debugging. You can mark a breakpoint on any line and debug it to see its value at runtime. Please check the value of 'historialString' to make sure it is not null.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the null problem without using the for loop, search.toJson and adding directly to the jsonlist.